# USB and Microcontroller communication problem

Tags: 12.04, usb, serial-port

I am new to the Linux world and am currently using Ubuntu 12.04. It is running in a Windows partition. I have developed a python program that reads in serial data from a micro-controller over the USB port. All was working fine till two days ago when it began crashing. On inputting `dmesg | grep tty` in to the console I get the following output:

```
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[   14.599394] cdc_acm 3-1:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[  290.236065] cdc_acm 3-1:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[ 1105.915191] cdc_acm 3-1:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```

Every time I connect and disconnected the USB I get a new line with the same data. Only difference been the time. Is this right or have I a problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Update:

The issue was with the micro-controller. It rebooted every time it did not receive a package from any sensors for a period of time. The micro-controller is a router on a wireless sensor network. Every time the micro controller rebooted its connection port was incremented e.g `ttyACM0` to `ttyACM1`. Upon connecting the controller to a Raspberry PI this stopped happening.

Comment: That does not show any problem. It seems normal as you are plugged in the micro-controller multiple times. When you wrote '... it began crashing' your mean your program? Also 'I get a new line with the same data.' you mean data your program read from serial port?

Comment: Hi Sneetsher. The issue was with the micro controller. It rebooted every time it did not recieve a package from any sensors for a period of time. The micro controller is a router on a wireless sensor network. every time the micro controller rebooted its connection port was incremented e.g ttyACM0 to ttyACM1. Upon connecting the controller to a raspberry pi this stopped happening. Thanks for taking time to write.

Comment: Nice to hear that. In case you want persistent USB dev naming, you may create a udev rule see http://hintshop.ludvig.co.nz/show/persistent-names-usb-serial-devices/ .

Comment: @Sneetsher. That link was very useful. its the permenant solution to the issue. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check USB Vendor ID, Product ID and Serial Number.

   ```
   $ dmesg | grep usb
   [...]
   [11427.635362] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
   [11427.730823] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=685e
   [11427.730830] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
   [11427.730834] usb 2-1.2: Product: SAMSUNG
   [11427.730838] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Android
   [11427.730842] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: S610275b03f86
   [11427.742314] usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
   [11427.742436] scsi8 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
   [11427.786013] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
   ```

   Or `udevadm info -a /dev/ttyUSB1` may be more complete.
2. Create new udev rules file. Example with rules for Android phone, Arduino, Bus pirate and an ARM kit.

   ```
   $ sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/99-my-usb-serial.rules
   SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="685e", ATTRS{serial}=="S610275b03f86", SYMLINK+="android"
   SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", ATTRS{serial}=="A6008isP", SYMLINK+="arduino"
   SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", ATTRS{serial}=="A7004IXj", SYMLINK+="buspirate"
   SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", ATTRS{serial}=="FTDIF46B", SYMLINK+="ttyUSB.ARM"
   ```

References:

- [Persistent names for usb-serial devices](http://hintshop.ludvig.co.nz/show/persistent-names-usb-serial-devices/)
- [Getting Started with BeagleBone & BeagleBone Black](http://beagleboard.org/Getting%20Started) or exactly [mkudevrule.sh](http://beagleboard.org/static/Drivers/Linux/FTDI/mkudevrule.sh)