# Autorun program after connecting Arduino nano

Tags: python, arduino, autorun

I have read few posts which explained how to write a script and save it on the USB flash drive, which will allow it to run as we connect the device.

I want to know if there is a way where we can overwrite Arduino nano device driver to allow it to run a python script already on the PC? 
I don't want user to always run the script before using the required functionality.

Comment: So, let me understand this: the script is on PC, when arduino is connected - run the script. Correct ?  Basically detect plugged in arduino and fire the script ? Also , what model of Arduino you have ?

Comment: Yes. Exactly!! I have arduino nano ATmegav328. Also, I would like it to happen to every PC I attach thay arduino, So, basically I would like to inclue that special program as a part of driver of this arduino.

Comment: Arduino itself doesn't  include a driver. Drivers are installed on each individual PC.  So we can't really make every computer run Python script. What we can do, is make one individual computer detect when Arduino is plugged in and run the script, but it has to live on that computer, not on Arduino. If you'd like me to post an answer about that , let me know.

Comment: Okay!! I know about cuttlefish which can do all such stuff, but it would be better if I know how it is done at the core. So your answer would be most welcome. ThankYou :)

Comment: Also, I wonder how wireless mouse starts working on any PC without installing any software.

Comment: wireless or USB mouses are not exactly overly complex devices. We had implemented a very very simple driver in my microcontrollers class that behaves like a mouse, and Linux kernel generally has drivers for mice built into it. So it is very different situation. But Arduino is a different device, and it generally uses serial ( aka UART ) driver for communication only. And in general it is very bad from the point of view of security to plug in device and run arbitrary python or C code in any computer.

Comment: Yeah. I understand. I am now looking for automating it in only my PC with the help of kernel modules if I am on a right track.

Comment: I've posted a draft of the answer. I will update it later in the week, as I am somewhat short on time

Answer (score 0):

#### NOTE: Answer is under construction, will be updated in steps.

General approach to run a script when a USB device is connected is to have a `udev` rule. UDev is a device manager system for Linux kernel, which has some userspace tools available. In particular, triggering a script upon device connection has been outlined in [How to run custom scripts upon USB device plug-in?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28548/85039) and in [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/435029/295286) on [USB and Microcontroller communication problem](http://USB%20and%20Microcontroller%20communication%20problem).

Basic steps:

1. Launch `udevadm monitor` or `dmesg -w`.
2. Connect the arduino
3. Note the output from commands in step 1
4. Create  `/etc/udev/rules.d/arduino.rules` file. You will need `ATTRS{idVendor}` and `ATTRS{product}` at least to make it work, the script should be launched via `RUN+="/full/path/to/script.py"` parameter. There are examples online, for instance, [strawlab/arduino-udev](https://github.com/strawlab/arduino-udev/blob/master/udev/99-arduino-udev.rules) on github shows how UDev rules for Arduino Nano could look like